# Web application to store a large amount of data client-side

Tags: javascript, ajax, database, web-applications

How can a web application store a very large amount of data client-side? (I'm talking concretely about allowing a capacity of some millions of records).
What I want to do here is to allow research of these records offline.
All of the users are using Chrome.

I was opting for indexedDb until I read that with about 400k records, it is almost unusable.
Then there is the Web SQL, but it had been deprecated.

I was then thinking that my last option would be to install a web server like apache with small script locally that would interact with my web application and store the records in a DB like MySQL. With AJAX I could access my script in localhost, but then there is the cross-domain problem.

I ran out of ideas

**Update**: clarification->

The main web application is running on a distant server. It has to be on a server as the application is used by several people at different locations (it is shared), and need to be accessed by smartphone, etc. The last idea was to install a web application locally (on all of the user's computer), that would interact with that distant web application to fetch the records from it and store them locally. Anyway it wouldn't work because of cross-domain issues I guess.

Comment: If you have to install a webserver to use a web app... well, you may as well just write it as a native app.

Comment: The main web application is running on a distant server. The last idea was to add a *second* web application locally, that would interact with that distant web application to fetch the records from it and store them locally. I updated the question to clarify, thank you.

Comment: Right, but if you have to install some big application... then you lost the advantage of making this web based and it would likely be easier to just create a native client which communicates with the remote server and can also store data locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see few alternatives:

1. don't you actually need a desktop application. I know, I know it is so 1990's...
2. installing a local web server and accessing your application via web browser is an option as well. But this is dangerously close to point 1.
3. you might consider developing a Java [applet](/questions/tagged/applet) and permitting it to use the file system

Comment: for point 1. The application needs to be used by several people at different locations + access to smartphones. it is a shared application, that's why it's on a distant. server
for point 2. read my *update*, I wasn't clear enough
I will investigate for java applet thanks

Comment: @Matthew: How do you intend on installing a webserver onto an arbitrary smart phone?

Comment: @Ed S. On Smartphone it will not be possible to use that functionality (offline research), only for desktop version.